# Why can't the polynomials have a root in $K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I want to show the following statement:

Each proper subfield of an algebraically closed field is not algebraically closed.

$$$$

Suppose that it doesn't hold. Let $F$ be an algebraically closed field and $K$ a proper subfield of $F$.

Suppose that $K$ is algebraically closed. That means that all the non-constant polynomials of $K[x]$ have a root in $K$.

Why is this impossible?

Comment: The statement you want to prove is false. For example, $\mathbb C$ contains $\bar{\mathbb Q}$, the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$ (and in fact $\mathbb C$ contains tons of algebraically closed subfields)

Comment: Ah ok... Thank you!! :-) @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Answer (score 2):

It's false, the set of complex numbers that are  a root to a polynomial with integer coefficients form an algebraic closed field that does not contain $\pi$.

Comment: Could you explain to me the part with $\pi$ ?

Comment: yeah, its the whole $\pi$ is trascendental thing.